# Capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, capitalization, hyphenation, cap

I'm trying to capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word with Rails:

```
"hello-world".capitalize
# => Hello-world

"hello-world".titleize
# => Hello World
```

Is there a quick way of doing this? If not then I will write a custom solution, I can figure that out, but I'm hoping there is some really quick and dirty method that can do this for me

Comment: Well, `#titelize` capitalizes both parts, doesn't it? Do you want to keep the hypen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try titleize, but also add gsub

```
"hello-world".titleize.gsub(' ', '-')
```

It returns:

```
irb(main):006:0> "hello-world".titleize.gsub(' ', '-')
"Hello-World"
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an [inflector](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/Inflector) that will do what you want, but you can do this, which is `quick and dirty`:

```
'hello-world'.split('-').map(&:capitalize).join('-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this i hope this will helping you

```
"hello-world".split('-').map(&:capitalize)*'-'
```

Comment: Thanks. Props for the `*'-'` at the end, didn't know about that!